# Regex to find first tag

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I use Notepad++, and I need to find the tags

```
<font face="arial" size="4">
```

till

```
</font></td>
```

I tried this:

```
<font face="arial" size="4">(.*)</font>(.*)</td>
```

but it finds all starting from the first line to the last line.  But I need it to find the first match of the first "font face" with its adjacent or closest /font/td tag, and then find the next in the same text.. etc.

Example text:

```
<font face="arial" size="4">text text text...sdfklj@skdjhgls:d</font></td>

<font face="arial" size="4">some text<br />
any more text
    </font> </td>

morel;owkjdgkd dhfksg h

<font face="arial" size="4">some text</font><p>
more text</font> </td>
```

---

Then I need to replace the two tags with:
the first with

```
<span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Times; lang=en-us">
```

and the second with:

```
</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try being lazy:

```
<font face="arial" size="4">[\s\S]*?</font>[\s\S]*?</td>
```

Use `[\s\S]` to match any character including newlines, and add the lazy quantifier `?` to match as few times as possible before the `</font>` and the `</td>` appear.

If there is only ever spaces between the `</font>` and `</td>` tags, you can obviously just use `\s*` instead of `[\s\S]*?`. (I note that your example html is malformed, as it contains a `</font>` tag following a `</font>` tag.)

You can use something along these lines to make the replacement:

```
<font face="arial" size="4">([\s\S]*?)</font>([\s\S]*?)</td>

<span style="font-size: 14pt; font-family: Times; lang=en-us">\1</span>\2</td>
```

Comment: works great..  thanks..  I need something else, to replace the tag with another tag (for example: <span>same text</endtag>) and keep all the text and atgs between the two "find" tags as is

Comment: @Mike. Added example replacement.

Comment: I tried the \1\2 but it removes the text..  I have updated the question with the example to be replaced with